# Does this video card support sound?

Tags: audio, graphics-card, hdmi

Probably a rookie question but here goes...I am looking to buy a new video card for a few year old PC which will be used as a media centre.  The card I am looking at is this one http://www.ebuyer.com/product/173708, with the main aim being to play blu-ray films.  In the product description it states that the card has 7.1 audio channel support, does this mean it will play the sound from the blu-ray through the HDMI, or do I need a separate sound card?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the HDMI output [will provide audio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI#Audio.2FVideo) to the TV (or monitor); all HD 4600 series cards support this. See [this article](http://www.anandtech.com/show/2622) for more info, or the ATI [spec](http://www.amd.com/us/products/desktop/graphics/ati-radeon-hd-4000/hd-4600/Pages/ati-radeon-hd-4600-specifications.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does. All the ATI radeon (at least the 4xxx series for sure) comes with HDMI with sound. If you install the card and the driver from ATI, you will get a new sound card called "ATI" or something like that. Switch to that for movies/whatever you want to push out through HDMI and there you go. That's all.